# append dictionary key to dataframe columns in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I am calculating moving averages for many columns and I want to append dictionary key to each newly created column indicating the original name of the columns and the window size.

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,4), columns = ('Time', 'A', 'B' ,'C'))
```

my window sizes dictionary looks like this. String 'ma_5' indicates the moving window size and ma_5 is the value.

```
ma_5 = 5
ma_4 = 4
ma_3 = 3
ma_2 = 2
ma_1 = 1
window_size = {'ma_5': ma_5, 'ma_4': ma_4, 'ma_3': ma_3, 'ma_2': ma_2, 'ma_1': ma_1}
```

I'm using this for loop to create moving averages columns for each window size.

```
def calculate_ma(frame):
    for col in frame[frame.columns.drop('Time')]:
        for key, value in window_size.items():
            frame[col + '_' + key] = frame[col].rolling(window=value).mean()
            return frame
```

Whilst I expect naming of new data columns look like A_ma_5, A_ma_4, A_ma_3, etc.. B_ma_5, B_ma_4, etc and so on, my dataframe columns were created based on the values of dictionary items and returned A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, B5, B4 etc... Appreciate pointers to fix the code. Thanks!

Comment: Indentation issue? move `return frame` to the left (under first `for`)

Comment: unfortunately not @AndrejKesely. I moved return frame back to the left still see the same column namings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to indent the `return frame` correctly:

```py
toy_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50, 4), columns=("Time", "A", "B", "C"))


ma_5 = 5
ma_4 = 4
ma_3 = 3
ma_2 = 2
ma_1 = 1
window_size = {"ma_5": ma_5, "ma_4": ma_4, "ma_3": ma_3, "ma_2": ma_2, "ma_1": ma_1}


def calculate_ma(frame):
    for col in frame[frame.columns.drop("Time")]:
        for key, value in window_size.items():
            frame[col + "_" + key] = frame[col].rolling(window=value).mean()
    return frame


out = calculate_ma(toy_df)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        Time         A         B         C    A_ma_5    A_ma_4    A_ma_3    A_ma_2    A_ma_1    B_ma_5    B_ma_4    B_ma_3    B_ma_2    B_ma_1    C_ma_5    C_ma_4    C_ma_3    C_ma_2    C_ma_1
0   0.908118  0.888868  0.242418  0.804369       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.888868       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.242418       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.804369
1   0.374466  0.014431  0.147990  0.775967       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.451649  0.014431       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.195204  0.147990       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.790168  0.775967
2   0.651480  0.300404  0.323260  0.276600       NaN       NaN  0.401234  0.157417  0.300404       NaN       NaN  0.237889  0.235625  0.323260       NaN       NaN  0.618979  0.526284  0.276600
3   0.791484  0.210554  0.560761  0.145779       NaN  0.353564  0.175130  0.255479  0.210554       NaN  0.318607  0.344003  0.442010  0.560761       NaN  0.500679  0.399449  0.211190  0.145779
4   0.925892  0.428807  0.268322  0.300750  0.368613  0.238549  0.313255  0.319680  0.428807  0.308550  0.325083  0.384114  0.414541  0.268322  0.460693  0.374774  0.241043  0.223265  0.300750
5   0.843775  0.179257  0.257408  0.265829  0.226691  0.279756  0.272873  0.304032  0.179257  0.311548  0.352438  0.362163  0.262865  0.257408  0.352985  0.247240  0.237453  0.283289  0.265829
6   0.048556  0.995064  0.701853  0.847105  0.422817  0.453421  0.534376  0.587161  0.995064  0.422321  0.447086  0.409194  0.479630  0.701853  0.367213  0.389866  0.471228  0.556467  0.847105
7   0.039803  0.268876  0.415468  0.598970  0.416512  0.468001  0.481066  0.631970  0.268876  0.440762  0.410763  0.458243  0.558661  0.415468  0.431687  0.503164  0.570635  0.723038  0.598970
8   0.644269  0.777825  0.745472  0.554984  0.529966  0.555256  0.680588  0.523350  0.777825  0.477705  0.530050  0.620931  0.580470  0.745472  0.513528  0.566722  0.667020  0.576977  0.554984

...and so on.
```

Comment: thanks! fixed the indent, also put the window_size dictionary outside the function and it works now :)